# Formik to skip validation for fields that equal their initial value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I don't want Formik to run the validaiton schema of a field if it's equal to its initial value at any point. I have looked everywhere on the web to achieve this but unfortunately could not find a solution.
The docs are very convoluted in regards to this simple functionality. There is a prop called `isInitialValid` but it's deprecated and no longer works. It says to use `initialErrors` as an alternative but there is no explanation on how to use it, especially in the same way I need.
Screenshot: [formik_docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28INW.png)
( https://formik.org/docs/api/formik )

If there is no way of achieving this in Formik then I thought perhaps to achieve it inside of the Yup validation schema itself, and so I would want to tell Yup to "run this entire validation only if a certain condition is met" (if the given value is not equal to initial value). So that is one of the potential solutions I tried implementing but I don't know how to do that with Yup. Of course it would be better if Formik has a solution, so this is plan B.

I have made simplified boilerplate code and will appreciate if answers use it. It's MUI/Formik and has the email field with an initialValue which should skip validation https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-sandbox-3bci5l?file=/src/App.js

For context: I am making a form that edits an item, so the initial values would all be filled with that item's properties, and it's possible that the dev team decides to add new validators for each property but we decided we don't want to force changes to previous values based on newly added validations. Even better would be to somehow make them into warning messages (so MUI would simply color the errors yellow) and still allow submit, but I'll put that aside for now since that would be much more complicated to achieve.

Thank you in advance for any help.